# If the user is disabled by admin, the active session of user must be killed

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have a Spring application that uses Spring Security.  Users with an `ADMIN` role can view a list of all users registered in the system and can disable (suspend) any user (for example, if the system usage terms and conditions are violated).  If the user so disabled then tries to login, they are denied login because their user account has been disabled.

However, if the user so disabled is logged in at the time their user account is disabled, they continue to use the system until they log out or their session times out.

We would like that when an admin user disables a user account, the user whose account was disabled must not be able to use the system further, even if they are logged in at the time of disablement of the account.

Is there a way to achieve this with Spring Security?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if(user.isDisabled()){

List principals = sessionRegistry.getAllPrincipals();
for(Object principal : principals){

AuthenticatedUser users = (AuthenticatedUser) principal;

```
                    String username= users.getUsername();
                    List<SessionInformation> sessionInformations = sessionRegistry.getAllSessions(users, false);
                    for(SessionInformation information : sessionInformations){
                        if(username.equalsIgnoreCase(user.getUserName())) {
                             information.expireNow();
                         }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

We have a similar functionality in our system where a user is forced to login again if their user rights are changed by the admin while they are already logged in to the system.

We have implemented it as follows:

1. All users are identified by their usernames (this is their security principal).
2. There is an in-memory cache that maintains principals whose access rights have been changed and the timestamp at which the rights were changed.
3. The part of the code that changes a user's access rights pushes the principal of the changed user and the current timestamp to the in-memory cache.
4. There is a servlet filter that examines each request before it is processed.  This filter picks up the principal for the user corresponding to the request and checks whether that principal exists in the in-memory cache with a timestamp later than the commencement time of the current session.  If the check passes, the current session is immediately invalidated and the user is redirected to the login page.  The principal is also removed from the cache.  If the principal is not found in the cache, the request is allowed to proceed as usual.

We use a distributed cache so that all the application servers maintain the same cache of principals, thereby allowing requests to be routed to any application server without loss of functionality.

There is the scenario where a user is not logged in and their access rights are changed, thereby pushing their principal into the cache.  When the user next logs in, the filter finds the user's principal in the cache but the cached timestamp is found to be earlier than the session commencement time so the user is allowed to use the system normally.

Comment: No, I have given you the general direction, writing the code is up to you.